# How to insert NA into every value of empty table when I read in in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a loop like this, which tried to combine all the excel files together. But some of my table is empty, which only have the headline but no values. I want to insert NA into those empty tables, in order to combine them correctly in the final summary file. How should I do that?

```
DataCC = dir('*-CC.xls');
namelist1={DataCC.name};
PlateNameCC=regexprep(namelist1,'-CC.xls','');
MeanAreaCC=[];
MeanGreyCC=[];
ColonyNumCC=[];
for w = 1: numel(DataCC)
    basefilenamedata=DataCC(w).name;
    T=readtable(basefilenamedata);
    if T.Area=[]
        MeanAreaCC =NA;
        MeanGreyCC=NA;
        MeanGreyCC=NA;
        ColonyNumCC=NA;
    else
        MeanAreaCC = [MeanAreaCC mean(T.Area)];
        MeanGreyCC = [MeanGreyCC mean(T.MeanGrey)];
        ColonyNumCC = [ColonyNumCC max(T.ColonyNum)];
    end
end
```

The empty excel file looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it two ways:

1. **Editing your code:**

Substitute the code part below:

```
if isempty(T.alpha)
     MeanAreaCC =NaN;
     MeanGreyCC=NaN;
     MeanGreyCC=NaN;
     ColonyNumCC=NaN;
```

That is a simple mistake, `=[]` is an assignment, not a comparative. And a comparison `==` is not good for structures. Note that is also `NaN`, not `NA`.

2. **Use another code:**

I actually used the Matlab import data/and generate script to do so.

```
%%Import the data
[~, ~, raw] = xlsread('E:\Matlabfiles\GaN_ZnO\Abs_test\test.xlsx','Sheet1','A2:C20');
raw(cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(x) && isnumeric(x) && isnan(x),raw)) = {''};

%%Replace non-numeric cells with NaN
R = cellfun(@(x) ~isnumeric(x) && ~islogical(x),raw); % Find non-numeric cells
raw(R) = {NaN}; % Replace non-numeric cells

%edit data
data = reshape([raw{:}],size(raw));
%% Create table
test = table;

%% Allocate imported array to column variable names
test.alpha = data(:,1);
test.beta = data(:,2);
test.gama = data(:,3);

%%Clear temporary variables
clearvars raw R;
```

However, to create `NaN` in cells that are not between numbers and have no extra values, you need to expand it manually on the part `'E:\myfiles\test.xlsx','Sheet1','A2:C20'`

In this case i have data after the second line, over three lines. As i show below.
Just in case, `test` is table, `data` a numeric matrix. However the picture is with the names wrong.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!! But I have question: now NaN is the empty value and its really empty in the excel file. But I want it to show NA instead of really empty. How should I change the code?

Comment: @Ziming You mean in the Excel or in Matlab? And you mean `NaN`?